# Lithium Battery Pack Cell Arrangement: Parallel First or. Series First (4P16S or 16S4P)?

Tags: lithium-ion, batteries, lithium

I am looking to arrange 64 individual LiFePo4 cells into a large 48V pack. So I can do 4P16S or 16S4P. All cells are new. I can add individual fuses to each cell if necessary. The capacity of each cell is 100Ah. What are the considerations and Pros and Cons of both arrangements. How can one decide which arrangement to go with? The cells will be balanced by an active BMS.

Comment: It is not clear how you mean for 4P16S to be physically different than 16S4P since they are electrically identical.

Comment: @DKNguyen, they are not. 4P16S is 16 packs of 4 cells connected in parallel. Than, you take the 16 individual packs and string them. The other one is 4 strings of 16 cells each, connected in parallel. It's Parallel First vs. Series First. When new, electrically it's the same. But failure modes are very different in case of cell failure.

Comment: @DKNguyen, you can see a diagram here of explanation: http://liionbms.com/php/wp_series_parallel.php

Comment: I'd do parallel first just because I don't want a million balance connectors and if one battery opens it doesn't take out the entire chain.

Comment: @DKNguyen, that's my instinct as well, and just fuse each cell, but I wanted to see if someone could post a Pros and Cons, maybe I am missing something, you know.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, but Why not both?
I personally would go `2p16s2p`. Then you don't need to disconnect all loads while doing maintenance on one of the packs...
Obviously you are limited by the number of cells in total, but I would always try to keep at least two batteries in parallel, for the aforementioned reason of availability.
So if we call our configuration `(n)p16s(m)p`, I would try to keep `m>=2`, and then try to keep `n>=m` for simplicity's sake (self balancing, less bms etc)

- 16 : 1p16s1p
- 32 : 1p16s2p
- 48 : 1p16s1p + 1p16s2p
- 64 : 2p16s2p
- 96 : 3p16s2p
- 128: 4p16s2p
- 192: 4p16s3p
- ...

Something like that. But obviously it depends on the specific use case...